# Unexpected log results from PowerShell script

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I have an automated script that is used to clean data off of remote computers. The script works great, but I am getting a blank report output. I am hoping to see a line of each system in the report showing a positive or negative result. Can you share a little knowledge and experience?

It's a little rough, but it's the first draft. Here is my code:

```
<##
Sets variables
##>
$Computers = Get-Content "C:\Tools\NodeScrub.txt"
$Day = (Get-Date).DayOfYear
$Year = get-date -format "MM-dd-yyyy"
$Date = "$Day.$Year"
$LogDir = "C:\Reports"

<##
Runs the command to delete all files older and "X" days
in the remote computers "C:\MGALFAUSER" folder.
The agreed upon history is anything older than 7 days.
The script is set to 8 days as a margin of safety.
##>

foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {Invoke-Command -Computername $Computer -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem "C:\MGALFAUSER\" -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-8))} | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$False} | Out-File -FilePath "$LogDir\$Date.txt" -Append -Force}
```

Everything works except the output. Where did I screw up?

Comment: Have you tried __Out-File -Append__  then add the -FilePath statement(s)?

Comment: Also, you might want to try the -LiteralPath statement  "string exact target file path". Cool script by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use local variables in a remote call without proper scoping. All code has a scope as does its objects, properties, et al.

> [about_Scopes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes)
>
> Example 5: Using a Local Variable in a Remote Command
>
> For variables in
> a remote command created in the local session, use the Using scope
> modifier. PowerShell assumes that the variables in remote commands
> were created in the remote session.
>
> The syntax is:

```
$Using:<VariableName>
```

> For example, the following commands create a $Cred variable in the
> local session and then use the $Cred variable in a remote command:

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
Invoke-Command $s {Remove-Item .\Test*.ps1 -Credential $Using:Cred}
```

> The Using scope was introduced in PowerShell 3.0. In PowerShell 2.0,
> to indicate that a variable was created in the local session, use the
> following command format.

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
Invoke-Command $s {
  param($c)
  Remove-Item .\Test*.ps1 -Credential $c
} -ArgumentList $Cred
```

Best Practices:

Simple strings use single quotes.
Variable expansion or some formatting use cases then double-quotes.

So, something like this.

```
# Sets variables
$Computers  = Get-Content 'C:\Tools\NodeScrub.txt'
$Day        = (Get-Date).DayOfYear
$Year       = Get-Date -format 'MM-dd-yyyy'
$Date       = "$($Day).$($Year)"
$LogDir     = 'C:\Reports'

<#
Runs the command to delete all files older and "X" days
in the remote computers "C:\MGALFAUSER" folder.
The agreed upon history is anything older than 7 days.
The script is set to 8 days as a margin of safety.##>

foreach ($Computer in $Computers) 
{
    Invoke-Command -Computername $Computer -ScriptBlock {
        Get-ChildItem 'C:\MGALFAUSER' -Recurse | 
        Where-Object {($PSItem.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-8))} | 
        Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
    } | Out-File -FilePath "$($Using:LogDir)\$($Using:Date.txt)" -Append -Force
}
```

You are already doing -Force, -confirm:false is redundant.